# C++ : forward declaring const with internal linkage

Tags: c++, constants, extern, linkage

I want to forward declare a const variable *without* giving it external linkage. It seems to me, however, that this is impossible because the `extern` keyword simultaneously means "this has external linkage" and "this is a variable declaration, not a definition", and I can't get one without the other:

```
//// main.cpp: ////

extern const char table[256];    // forward declaration. External linkage.
// const char table[256];        // Error: table requires an initializer
// static const char table[256]; // Same error

// foo uses table so I need it forward declared:
char foo()
{
    // uses table
}

const char table[256] = {...}; // Actual definition
```

Is my understanding correct? Are there any workarounds?

Comment: @JesperJuhl And how to make a forward declaration of a constant array without its initialization?

Comment: probably not a good idea anyway to have a global array like that, instead pass it to 'foo' and use std .. foo(std::array<char,256> & table)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First of all, a forward declaration is defined only for types. You can type

```
class X;
```

and then use `X *` for example.

What you are trying to achieve here, is declare *symbol* before actual usage.
The only way I know to do this is via `extern` keyword.

But if want to make symbol linkage internal, *anonymous namespace* can help

```
namespace {
extern const char table[256]; // symbol declaration. Internal linkage.
}

char foo() {
    // use table
}
namespace {
const char table[256] = {...}; // symbol definition. Internal linkage.
}
```

Here is a test you can do

```
$ cat test.cc
extern const char moo[4];
char foo() { return moo[2]; }
const char moo[4] = {0};
$ g++  -c test.cc -o test.o -O3 && g++ test.o -shared -o test.so && nm -gD test.so | grep moo
00000000000005ad R moo
$
```

```
$ cat test.cc
namespace {
    extern const char moo[4];
}
char foo() { return moo[2]; }
namespace {
    const char moo[4] = {0};
}
$ g++  -c test.cc -o test.o -O3 && g++ test.o -shared -o test.so && nm -gD test.so | grep moo
$
```

Comment: anonymous namespace make scene only in single translation unit. When he wants to share instance between cpp using header file, then anonymous namespace will lead to duplication of instance. In case of trivially created types it is not a problem, since linker will clean it up. Your version should lead to linking issue.

Comment: I think any declaration which is not a definition, like `void func();` or `extern int count;` can be considered a forward declaration.

Comment: @MarekR The example suggests the variable is not in a header file. Plus the question says internal linkage or no linkage is wanted, which would always lead to that issue if in a header file.